# How much MB will Apple add to my .ipa when publishing it through appstore?

Tags: iphone, publishing

"When your application is approved by Apple to sell on the App Store, it is encrypted for DRM purposes and re-compressed. When the encryption is added, the size of the compressed file will increase." Most people I asked experience an increase of around 2MB, but can tell someone tell me exactly how many MB will be "added", or is it different for each app?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It will be different for each app.

The size of your app is usually only important when it approaches the size limit imposed by the iOS for downloading new apps over cellular networks.  If the iPhone is connected via WiFi, then the iOS imposes no limit.  If users are downloading your app to their desktop computer then Apple imposes no limit. (Internet service providers may impose limits, but Apple has no control of that.)

The limit is 20 Megabytes in the U.S. with AT&T. I don't know if there are different limits with different carriers or different regions.

The only way to know what the resulting size will be is to look at what is on the App Store after Apple has run their software on it. It is always possible that Apple's own compression software may actually shrink the delivered file.

I have noticed in the past that iTunes on my Mac will re-compress an IPA file I made. Once iTunes has made a copy of it, you can right-click the app and "Show In Finder. It may or may not be a good comparison to what Apple's servers will do.

If you worry about the 20 Megabyte limit, then you may want to give yourself some percentage margin for error and limit your app to a smaller size when you ship it to Apple.

Comment: IIRC, they'll now warn you if you're going to hit the limit when uploading the .ipa.

Answer (score 0):

Submission to the app store should not add any noticeable bulk to your app. I have not noticed any .ipa size differences from the file I share for testing vs the download size after submission.

As the other answer stated, if you bump into any size restrictions, you will be notified during the submission process.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I just uploaded a 77MB ipa file and Apple says it's 103MB. So, it added 26MB. Looks strange. This is the worst case I have seen so far.

Usually it has been less than 10MB.